# What is INF in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I found this definition in Isabelle

```
definition (in topological_space) nhds :: "'a ⇒ 'a filter"
  where "nhds a = (INF S∈{S. open S ∧ a ∈ S}. principal S)"
```

What is INF? I can't find anything in query tab nor can I jump to definition with Ctrl+Click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already answered the question yourself: `INF x∈A. f x` is simply the infimum of f(x) ranging over all x ∈ A.

But let me explain as well what it means in this particular context: `principal S` is the filter for which `eventually P (principal S)` simply means that `P` holds on all values in the set `S`.

We now take the infimum of that over all the open sets that contain a certain point `x`. This then gives us a filter where `eventually P (nhds x)` means that there *exists* an open set that contains `x` and on which this property holds. In other words: `P` holds for any point sufficiently close to `x` (including `x` itself).

Answer (score 0):

It is infimum of complete lattice

```
class Inf = 
   fixes Inf :: "'a set ⇒ 'a"  ("⨅ _" [900] 900)
```

This syntax is declared as

```
syntax
  "_INF1"     :: "pttrns ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'b"           ("(3INF _./ _)" [0, 10] 10)
  "_INF"      :: "pttrn ⇒ 'a set ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'b"  ("(3INF _∈_./ _)" [0, 0, 10] 10)
  "_SUP1"     :: "pttrns ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'b"           ("(3SUP _./ _)" [0, 10] 10)
  "_SUP"      :: "pttrn ⇒ 'a set ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'b"  ("(3SUP _∈_./ _)" [0, 0, 10] 10)

syntax
  "_INF1"     :: "pttrns ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'b"           ("(3⨅_./ _)" [0, 10] 10)
  "_INF"      :: "pttrn ⇒ 'a set ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'b"  ("(3⨅_∈_./ _)" [0, 0, 10] 10)
  "_SUP1"     :: "pttrns ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'b"           ("(3⨆_./ _)" [0, 10] 10)
  "_SUP"      :: "pttrn ⇒ 'a set ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'b"  ("(3⨆_∈_./ _)" [0, 0, 10] 10)
```

It's in `Complete_Lattices.thy` (https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL/outline.pdf) under section "Syntactic infimum and supremum operations" .